# print service without wifi connection is not working

Tags: android

I have problem with my print service running on Huawei P8 lite and Honor 6 (from Huawei). My print service (inherited from PrintService) works well while I am connected to some wifi. But when I am not connected to any wifi, even if wifi module is on, the OS is not calling my method "PrinterDiscoverySession.onStartPrinterDiscovery(...)", which should add my printer.

1. observation: the problem starts after I updated OS on Huawei P8 from Android 5 to Android 6
2. observation: with OnlePlus One (Android 6) it works well.
3. observation: it is not working, if wifi module is on, I am not connected to any network and I am using only mobile data

Am I missing something? I have a theory, that Huawei is not calling "onStartPrinterDiscovery(...)" because it predicts, that my service needs connection to local network. Can I tell the OS, that my service can work without wifi ?

Comment: This is not the normal OS behavior, I think it's a device thing so you may want to file it against Huawei directly. Just curious, are you adding a bluetooth printer? Does it have the same behavior if bluetooth is on?

Comment: It is independent on bluetooth status. I created whole new app, that prints the documents into PDF. The method "PrinterDiscoverySession.onStartPrinterDiscovery(...)" is still not called.